# Customize the message Tumblr sends to Twitter

Tags: twitter, tumblr

I have my Tumblr set-up to publish to Twitter as well. Currently it says

> Photo: [URL]

This is not very descriptive, are there any options other than `[URL]` that can be used to  automate the publish ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way to change the default message that gets sent to Twitter, but you can customize it individually each time you create a new Tumblr post. The `Send to Twitter` checkbox in the right-hand sidebar has a little `edit` link next to it. Click that, and it looks like this:

[image: custom tweet]

Voila - slightly less boring than the default text.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I did for the while. I just assumed they would at least allow say for example a [caption] option or [title] option since you can fill that info on the main section when tumbling.

Comment: Yeah, that seems like a no-brainer sort of feature... but if there are any options other than [URL] I can't figure out what they are.